# How often should I clean my BMX bike?

Tags: maintenance

I recently got my bike and rode it for a good 4 hours yesterday.

I'm pretty new to BMX riding, and really want to maintain my bike well.

I hear people clean their bike every time they finish, but was wondering if that is necessary.

Comment: The chain needs to be reasonably clean and properly lubricated, and you want to remove any crud that might build up around the brakes and derailers.  Otherwise, cleaning is just cosmetic.  Some people are proud of how clean their bikes are, some are proud of how dirty.

Comment: There are no derailers on a bmx  :P

Answer (score 2):

A clean bike is a happy bike. No, cleaning every speck.of sort off the frame after each ride isn't necessary.

However, wiping down the frame, and wiping any extra dirt or crud from the hubs, brakes and chain can only help keep your bike in good shape for as long as possible.

Make sure to lightly lube the chain once a week or so. And every couple of weeks, take a set of Allen keys and check that none of the bolts on your bike are coming loose.

Take it in for a tune every 6 months to a year, and you should be good to go. :)